# Gapless modes at the boundary between topological insulator and normal insulator

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, topological-insulators, topological-phase

I am currently learning about topology in condensed matter physics. I think I understand most of how topological indeces come about and differences between Z and Z2 indeces and the symmetries that play a role. Though, I still have one (as it seems) very basic question. In a lot of articles and books I read I repeatedly came across statements like:

> *"At the interface between such a standard insulator and a topological insulator, it is not
>   possible for the « band structure » to interpolate continuously between a topological insulator and the vacuum
>   without closing the gap. This forces the gap to close at this interface leading to metallic states of topological
>   origin.*" (M. Fruchart, D. Carpentier, arXiv: 1310.0255)

My question is just: Why?

Why does the gap need to close or the other way around: Why can I have a topological phase transition if the gap closes at the interface?
And furthermore, looking e.g. at a 3D Z2 TI: Why are the emerging states at such an interface linearly dispersed and spin helical?

Comment: Is this question about interfaces or bulk transitions?

Comment: hm..kind of both, isn't it? The topological invariant is a bulk property. As soon as I bring two bulk materials together I have to have a transition from one bulk invariant to the other. Though, this happens at the interface and only there the gap therefore needs to close.

Comment: @RyanThorngren Well, that's the thing: At least the folk idea is that this is the same.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch It's completely possible that I "only" have a folk understanding of the matter here.

Comment: They're not quite the same. There are interfaces that can be gapped (but carry non-trivial topological degrees of freedom), but at a phase transition the gap always has to close (but can be first order or continuous).

Comment: @Ryan Thorngren Ok, but I think this is my question or somehow my confusion: Why is a phase transition only possible if the gap closes?

Comment: Intuitively, if you do a variation of a gapped Hamiltonian, the ground state changes by a local unitary circuit with "range" proportional to the inverse gap. To have a phase transition, the system needs to rearrange itself at the largest length scales, so the gap has to at least dip below one over the system size.

Comment: @Thomas Then you should maybe clean up what you mean.  Are you talking about the bulk gap as you change the Hamiltonian in parameter space, the edge gap as you change it in real space, or sth else?

Comment: @RyanThorngren *"There are interfaces that can be gapped (but carry non-trivial topological degrees of freedom)"* -- but doesn't that mean that the interface isn't gapped (=a trivial gapped 1D phase), in the sense that there are degenerate states at the edge?

Comment: @Ryan Thorngren Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am too much of an experimetalist to have an intuitive picture of what you say. But I will try to find a way there.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch I am talking about the edge gap at the real space interface where two materials of different bulk topologies meet.

Comment: @Thomas I think in full generality this is not true, there are systems which have trivial edges yet are in a non-trivial phase.  For free fermions, the situation is different.

Comment: But then how do I need to understand the statement I cited in my original question? It sounds quite general to me.

Comment: @Thomas What you quote is about free fermions, not general topological order.  (The title of your question suggests otherwise.)  Also, please use @[username] otherwise I don't get notified.

Comment: @ Norbert Schuch Ok, thank you for the clarification. My question is about what I quote.

Comment: @Thomas You must not leave a space after the @ , or in the username.  (But you can only use the beginning of the username.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch thank you for the help, I see now that it's tagging you this way. So, do you happen to have an (intuitive) answer to my question regarding free fermions as in the quote I cite?